# kendo UI asynchronous uplaod on Razor Page returns 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kendo-asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I am trying to use Kendo UI async upload on Razor Page (No controller) But I get 404 error

Index.cshtml page-

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="">
        <form asp-action="" class="" id=""  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="">Review Type</label>
                <div class="">               
                    <select asp-for="ReviewType" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.ReviewTypes, "ReviewTypeLookupId", "ReviewTypeName"))" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class=""></label>
                <div class="">
                    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                          .Name("files")
                          .Async(a => a
                            .Save("Index?handler=Save", "UploadManagement")
                              .Remove("Remove", "UploadManagement/Index")
                              .AutoUpload(true)
                          )
                          )
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" id="submit-all" class="btn btn-default">Upload </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Index.cshtml.cs Page

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult OnPostSave(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
        {
            // The Name of the Upload component is "files"
            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    //var fileContent = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);

                    //// Some browsers send file names with full path.
                    //// We are only interested in the file name.
                    //var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileContent.FileName.Trim('"'));
                    //var physicalPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "App_Data", fileName);

                    //// The files are not actually saved in this demo
                    ////file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                }
            }

            // Return an empty string to signify success
            return Content("");
        }
```

Error - 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: With razor pages you need to set path to Index?handler=Save and change action name to OnPostSave?

Comment: Did that. But I still get 404. Please see updated code.

Comment: When the page is rendered, what does the url show?

Comment: https://localhost:44328/UploadManagement/Index?handler=Save

Comment: If that path is valid then the issue must be with model binding.  I'm not that familiar w/ razor pages, but don't you need a `BindProperty` attribute?  This was also discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122555/dropzone-on-razor-page-returns-400-status-code.

Comment: Does not help. Still not working

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this, is to not use `.Save(string action, string controller)` or any overload of this, but `.SaveUrl(string url)`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("files")
    .Async(a => a
        .SaveUrl("./Index?handler=Save")
        .AutoUpload(true)
))
```

This will also work, if you are in a non-default area and the url to the page itself is acually `/area-url/Index?handler=foo`